# How to use Highcharts.js with ES6

Tags: javascript, highcharts, ecmascript-6

I've tried everything possible to get Highcharts to work with Babel / Browserify / ES6 imports. I'm getting a `TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).highcharts is not a function`.

In my controller i've instantiated my `Chart` class and call `renderLineChart` method. My view with my content is already rendered.

I've tested Jquery too. It's ok.

```
import $ from "jquery";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);

export default class Chart {
    constructor(content) {
        this._content = content;
    }

    renderLineChart() {
        alert($("#input").val());
        var chart1; // globally available
        $(this._content).highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }],
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do `$(\`${this._content}\`)` over just `$(this._content)` -- I think you are over es6ing your code a bit...

Comment: Also you did not import any jquery lib here for highcharts. Maybe you meant to use `Highcharts.Chart ` instead?

Comment: @Neal Using `import Highcharts from "highcharts";` doesn't import Highcharts Chart ?

Comment: It imports the Highcharts library -- I am not sure if it imports the jQuery plugin.

Comment: @Neal I'm importing Jquery line above of highcharts

Comment: Yes... but you are not importing any highcharts jquery plugin...

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in a live demo like Plunker or JSFiddle?